# Having permission denied exception when executing terminal command using Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec on Mac

Tags: java, macos, exception, permission-denied

I am trying to start the terminal and run a command automatically by using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, but it gives me following exceptions:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/Utilities": error=13, Permission denied
```

I found the terminal app and changed permission to `read&write` since I have the administrator account, but it still gives me the same exception.

I tried to open other document on my mac using the same way, it shows up to have the same exception. Is there any other way I can execute commands on terminal at runtime?

Here is the code I have :

```js
import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenTerminal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OpenTerminal ot = new OpenTerminal();
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/Utilities open - a Terminal");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `/Applications/Utilities open - a Terminal` is not a valid shell command, so thats not going to work regardless. Try `open -a Terminal` instead.

Answer (score 0):

/Applications/Utilities is a directory. You can't execute it.